# Docker quickstart terminal not opening

Tags: windows, docker

I am new to this Docker world.I have installed Docker toolbox 1.8.2a on my windows machine.It has created desktop icon of docker terminal,Virtual box and Kitematic.
Now when i click on docker quickstart terminal its not opening giving error.
"C:/Program" is not recognised as internal or external operable program or batch file.

Comment: how about to reinstall it with path without space, such as: `C:/docker/`

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is put `"` around your path, i.e. `"C:\Program Files\...\..."`. The space in `Program Files` isn't automatically detected as belonging together. `C:\Program` will be evaluated as a prgram call, which will obviously fail.

Comment: i have given the path as "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox" in environment variable.still the problem is coming.